# Loop through filenames with spaces within a path

Tags: bash, scripting

I wanted to pass the path name to the script, but my path has spaces (eg. /Users/netto/iTunes \Media/Music/).
I have tried putting the actual path directly on the for loop, and I was able to get all the files. Unfortunately, I could not pass it as variable. I have tried both double quote, and single quote. This is what I have currently

```
$PATH=$1
for f in $PATH; do
   echo "Processing file $f " 
done
```

Please let me know on how to do this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `for f in "$1"/*; do
   echo "Processing file $f "; 
done`

Comment: few notes : 1) don't use `PATH` as a variable name, it is reserved by the system. 2) correct attribution is done without the `$` for the declared variable, i.e. `MY_VAR=$1` 3) use proper quotation : `MY_VAR="$1"`

Comment: Technically, quotes are not strictly required for variable assignment. As documented [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters), word splitting and filename expansion are not performed during assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop over directories with whitespace in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4895484/608639). Also see [Bash loop command through list containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36173381/608639)

Answer (score 4):

Spaces in variables are expanded at command level, so to solve the problem you can either put quotation marks around "$1" (so spaces are properly escaped) or use bash arrays.

Here is two example that should work:

```
 #!/bin/bash
DIR="$1"
for f in "$DIR"/* 
do
  echo "Processing file $f " 
done
```

or using bash arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=("$1"*)
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  echo "Processing file $f " 
done
```

Comment: While using `DIR` or `FILES` is better than `PATH`, all-caps names as a whole are in namespace used by standard-defined tools. Better to use `dir` or `files`; see relevant POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, defining the namespace with lower-case characters as "reserved for applications" (like your script).