# Looping through directories that have space in their name

Tags: bash, loops

I am sorry if someone asked this question gain, but I didn't find a solution which worked for me.

I wrote a small bash script, which works with normal folders. It should run a command for every Subfolder. But if there is a space in a Folder Name, there is a problem.

If there is a Folder called "New Folder" in /share/Download, the script will try to access to the folder "/share/Download/New" (instead of "New Folder")

i also tried with echo "$d"

```
    for d in `find /share/Download -mindepth 1 -type d`
do
    echo
    echo $d
    curl http://localhost:2345/api/command -X POST -d '{"name": "something", "path": "'"$d"'"}' --header "X-Api-Key:123456789"
    echo
done
```

Comment: This could help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. Use `IFS` to tell when to break lines. In this case, add `IFS=$'\n'` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Also read [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Comment: If you don't need to recursively search subfolders, `for d in /share/Download/*/; do` will suffice.

Comment: @PraveenP, that's buggy -- it'll still expand globs, and directories can have newlines in their names. If you have a directory created with `mkdir '*'`, for example, then even with `IFS=$'\n'`, iterating over it will then iterate over *all contents* of that directory, including non-directory files not returned by `find` at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I though Unix don't allow folder or file name with special characters such as `\n`? Which turn into `n`.

Comment: @PraveenP, incorrect -- they are allowed (in general; some filesystems may be more restrictive, but ext3/ext4/btrfs/etc on Linux permit them with no problem). Run `mkdir $'\n'` to test. Changing `\n` into `n` is a side effect of `read` without `-r`, or using an incorrect quoting type.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see what you mean now. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop over directories with whitespace in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4895484/608639). Also see [Bash loop command through list containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36173381/608639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shell is doing [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) on `find`'s output and that is the reason you are having the trouble.

Use process substitution to properly read the output of `find`:

```
while read -r d; do
  # your logic
done < <(find /share/Download -mindepth 1 -type d)
```

Even better, make `find` emit NUL terminated output so that directories that have a newline in them would be handled appropriately as well:

```
while read -r -d '' d; do
  # your logic
done < <(find /share/Download -mindepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601) can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I allready found the problem and a solution after more research.

for d in isn't whitespace save.

The following code did the trick:

```
    find  /share/Download -mindepth 1 -type d|while read fname; do
  curl http://localhost:1234/api/command -X POST -d '{"name": "something", "path": "'"$fname"'"}' --header "X-Api-Key:123456789"
done
```

Comment: Needs to be `while IFS= read -r fname` to correctly handle names that start and end with spaces or contain backslashes. And even that's buggy, because names with backslashes or literal double quotes will generate invalid JSON. If you want to generate content that's guaranteed to be correctly-escaped JSON, use `jq`.

Comment: `curl ... -d "$(jq -c --arg fname "$fname" '{"name": "something", "path": $fname}')"` is guaranteed to generate well-formed JSON, no matter what your filenames are. And see the advice from codeforester about using `-print0` and `IFS= read -r -d '' fname`