# How to loop though directories and move them to another location when directory name has spaces and directory has specific file extensions

Tags: linux, unix

I have a folder with the following directories

```
$ pwd
/d/xxx
'Anupam Roy - Zulfiqar (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack)'/
'Zulm Ka Jawab [1995] [Soundtrack]{Original Release  Melody  Top Star  MCD No. 406  CD}'/
```

The first directory has a list of files with extension .flac
The second directory has anothet folder named

```
'Bappi Lahiri - Zulm Ka Jawab (1995) [FLAC] {Melody MCD-406}'/
```

My requirement is loop through all the directories in /d/xxx and move them to another location. If the directory has flac files I want to skip that directory.

In this case I want to move 'Bappi Lahiri - Zulm Ka Jawab (1995) [FLAC] {Melody MCD-406}'/ and skip 'Anupam Roy - Zulfiqar (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack)'/

I have witten a script but that doesnt work beacsue the directory name has spaces

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in D:/xxx/*/; do
    count=`ls -l *.flac 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    if [ -d "$d" ] && [ $count == 0 ]; then
        mv $d D:/krishna/
        #$echo "$d"
    fi
done
```

Comment: can you try with `double quoting` around the directory with spaces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop over directories with whitespace in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4895484/608639)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the script a bit now Im running the script from D:\xxx

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in */; do
    echo $d
    cd "$d"
    count=`ls -l *.flac 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    cd ..
    echo $count
    if [ -d "$d" ] && [ $count == 0 ]; then
        mv $d D:/krishna/
        #$echo "$d"
    fi
done
```

But this is giving errors

```
$ ./dcdcopy.sh
Anupam Roy - Zulfiqar (Original Motion Picture Soundtrack)/
6
Zulm Ka Jawab [1995] [Soundtrack]{Original Release Melody Top Star MCD No. 406 CD}/
0
mv: cannot stat 'Zulm': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'Ka': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'Jawab': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '[1995]': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '[Soundtrack]{Original': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'Release': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'Melody': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'Top': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'Star': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'MCD': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'No.': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '406': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'CD}/': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in */; do
    echo $d
    cd "$d"
    count=`ls -l *.flac 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
    cd ..
    echo $count
    if [ -d "$d" ] && [ $count == 0 ]; then
        mv "$d"/* D:/krishna/
        #$echo "$d"
    fi
done
```